# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 14 requested, with a size of 14

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I populating a database colums and diaplying in table view. I am getting `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsError`.

Here is my code:

```
while(rows.isValidRow())
{

date=rows.fieldByName('Date');

displaydate(date);

Ti.API.info(';'+date); 

 while( date==rows.fieldByName('Date') )
{


    intime=rows.fieldByName('StartTime');
    outtime=rows.fieldByName('EndTime');
    taskname=rows.fieldByName('TaskName');
    note=rows.fieldByName('Note');


    displayreport(intime,outtime,'',taskname,note); 

    Ti.API.info(';'+intime+';'+outtime+';'+taskname+';'+note);

    rows.next();        

}   
      rows.next();

}      


rows.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have too many `rows.next();` in your sample. revisit how you have constructed your loop.